# Understanding string method strip

Tags: python

After initializing a variable x with the content shown in below, I applied strip with a parameter. The result of strip is unexpected. As I'm trying to strip "ios_static_analyzer/", "rity/ios_static_analyzer/" is getting striped.

Kindly help me know why is it so.

```
>>> print x
/Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/ios_static_analyzer/

>>> print x.strip()
/Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/ios_static_analyzer/

>>> print x.strip('/')
Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/ios_static_analyzer

>>> print x.strip('ios_static_analyzer/')
Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/secu

>>> print x.strip('analyzer/')
Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/ios_static_

>>> print x.strip('_analyzer/')
Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/ios_static

>>> print x.strip('static_analyzer/')
Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/io

>>> print x.strip('_static_analyzer/')
Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/io

>>> print x.strip('s_static_analyzer/')
Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/io

>>> print x.strip('os_static_analyzer/')
Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/secu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need, I think, is `replace`:

```
>>> x.replace('ios_static_analyzer/','')
'/Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/'
```

> string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
>
> ```
> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.
> ```

So you can replace your string with nothing and get the desired output.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [`str.strip` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters
>   removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of
>   characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument
>   defaults to removing whitespace. **The chars argument is not a prefix or
>   suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:**

So, it removes all the characters in the parameter, from both the sides of the string.

For example,

```
my_str = "abcd"
print my_str.strip("da")  # bc
```

**Note:** You can think of it like this, it stops removing the characters from the string when it finds a character which is not found in the input parameter string.

To actually, remove the particular string, you should use `str.replace`

```
x = "/Users/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/ios_static_analyzer/"
print x.replace('analyzer/', '')
# /Users/msecurity/Desktop/testspace/Hy5_Workspace/security/ios_static_
```

But replace will remove the matches everywhere,

```
x = "abcd1abcd2abcd"
print x.replace('abcd', '')  # 12
```

But if you want to remove words only at the beginning and ending of the string, you can use RegEx, like this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^{0}|{0}$".format("abcd"))
x = "abcd1abcd2abcd"
print pattern.sub("", x)   # 1abcd2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is helpful. I'll make a habit of going through the official documents. Probably that would had helped. Anyways Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Python `x.strip(s)` remove from the begginning or the end of the string `x` any character appearing in `s` ! So `s` is just a set of characters, not a string being matched for substring.

Answer (score 0):

[string.strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes a set of characters given as an argument. The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.

Answer (score 0):

`strip` does not remove the string given as argument from the object; it removes *the characters* in the argument.
In this case, `strip` sees the string `s_static_analyzer/` as an iterable of characters that needs to be stripped.